# AngularJS - directive dynamic template. Variable is treated as text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, treegrid

I need to modify this Angular component: http://khan4019.github.io/tree-grid-directive/test/treeGrid.html (more info: https://github.com/khan4019/tree-grid-directive)

My problem is simple. Tree-grid not allow to formatting specified column e.g. by filters. For example I want to transform every cell in `description` column to uppercase. Look here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6vSAKpZtoEB98fTOqtA4?p=preview

In **treeGridTest.js**, lines 36-41 are responsible by column definitions:

```
$scope.col_defs = [
    { field: "Description"},
    { field: "Area"},
    { field: "Population"},
    { field: "TimeZone", displayName: "Time Zone"}
];
```

In **tree-grid-directive.js** file, 31th line (part of template code) responsibles for printing data in cells:

`<td ng-repeat=\"col in colDefinitions\">{{row.branch[col.field]}}</td>\`

I would like to have solution known from ng-grid, so first, I added new element to each object in `$scope.col_defs` which I called `cellDef` :

```
$scope.col_defs = [
    { field: "Description", cellDef: "{{row.branch[col.field] | uppercase}}"},
    { field: "Area", cellDef: "{{row.branch[col.field]}}"},
    { field: "Population", cellDef: "{{row.branch[col.field]}}"},
    { field: "TimeZone", displayName: "Time Zone", cellDef: "{{row.branch[col.field]}}"}
];
```

and I replaced 31th line in **tree-grid-directive.js** file by:

`<td ng-repeat=\"col in colDefinitions\">{{col.cellDef}}</td>\`

But instead of uppercase description, there is text `{{row.branch[col.field]}}` in every cell in the column, just have a look:

http://plnkr.co/edit/97fcUbUKC5e5svh3r7ML?p=preview

How to fix this? i would be grateful for your help, I'm quite new in java script and angularJS framework.

Comment: don't know will it help you, but try this tree-grid-directive.js -> line: 31 -> <td ng-repeat=\"col in colDefs\">{{row.branch[col.field] | uppercase}}</td>\

Comment: @Dart, but angular  won't know about my filter which I used on Description column (text is not in uppercase)

Comment: use this(ugly, but look like works) same position line 31: <td ng-repeat=\"col in colDefs\"><div ng-if=\"col.field != \'Description\'\">{{row.branch[col.field]}}</div><div ng-if=\"col.field == \'Description\'\">{{row.branch[col.field] | uppercase}}</div></div></td>\

Comment: yeah, it works, but this is completely inflexible solution. I'll use many filters on different columns, so I can't "hard-coded" this directly in template.

Comment: use extra field like {..., uppercase: true}, then <div ng-if="uppercase"> {{field | uppercase}}

Answer (score 0):

I just defined a css class

```
.col-uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Then at line 31, changed to:

```
<td ng-repeat="col in colDefinitions" class="{{col.cssClass || ''}}">{{row.branch[col.field]}}</td>
```

And it works.

Ahh, don't forget to define a css class property for your column definitions

```
{ field: "Description", cssClass:"col-uppercase" }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for your `cellDef` to work, Add the key-value `cellDef: 'cellDef'` to your `col_defs` for that particular field, and then assign value to your `cellDef` in your JS.